# When a suspended user tries to ask a question, the screen looks the exact same as an automatic question ban

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, account-suspension

When an account has been manually suspended by a moderator and the user is trying to post a question via [/questions/ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), it says:

> You have reached your question limit. Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See [the Help Center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) to learn more.

[image]

The screen looks the exact same as it does to a user subject to an automatic question ban. The help center link points to the article on automatic question bans.

It would be clearer to say that the account has been suspended, e.g.:

> Sorry, we are currently not accepting questions from your account because it has been suspended till 2021-04-29.

preferably with "suspended" linking to the mod message stating so.

Comment: I believe that 'internally' a suspension works as getting question and answer banned, or uses the same checks . That  said, 'between' the mod message and your account page - wouldn't it be somewhat obvious that you're suspended?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't often check my account page, and also often hide my inbox/rep notifications.