# What are the additional paragraphs on the delete profile page that appear for suspended users?

Tags: support, profile-page, account-suspension, deleted-accounts

Post on ruSO.meta [Не переведена часть текста на странице удаления учётной записи заблокированного участника](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12359/176217) claims that in case of vising the [delete profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/delete/current) during user suspension there are some extra paragraphs compare with case of no suspended user. But the OP didn't make a screenshot and didn't remember the text as well.

If it's true, how can I get the text of that addition? Maybe someone from developers could post it here?

Comment: In Russian or English? Make a sock puppet and ask a moderator on the relevant site to suspend it so you can see. (I would not use your regular account for that since you did nothing to deserve a suspension and it would complicate running in a moderator election.)

Comment: @Laurel it doesn't matter. But according to post on ruSO.meta that text doesn't have translation yet.

Comment: It just talks about how deleting and recreating your account won't get you out of the suspension and/or question ban.

Comment: @CodyGray do you have exact text? I would like to translate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seems to be a fair amount of [variability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_recombination) here. For example, when I visit the [delete page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/delete/current) here on MSE for my own account, I see:

> ## Delete Profile
>
> ---
>
> Before confirming that you would like your profile deleted, we'd like to take a moment to explain the implications of deletion:
>
> - Deletion is irreversible, and you will have no way to regain any of your original content, should this deletion be carried out and you change your mind later on.
> - Your questions and answers will remain on the site, but will be disassociated and anonymized (the author will be listed as "user153008") and will not indicate your authorship even if you later return to the site.
>
> We're sorry to hear you would like your profile to be deleted. While we respect your decision to proceed with this process, we'd like to offer you the option of having any concerns or specific incidents heard out before doing so. If you'd like to talk to someone, please feel free to [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) for further assistance.
>
> Confirming deletion will only delete your profile on Meta Stack Exchange - it will not affect any of your other profiles on the Stack Exchange network. If you want to delete multiple profiles, you'll need to visit each site separately and request deletion of those individual profiles.
>
> ☑️ I have read the information stated above and understand the implications of having my profile deleted. I wish to proceed with the deletion of my profile.

I see almost exactly the same text (with the obvious site-name and link substitutions) when I go to delete my profile on Stack Overflow (where I am a moderator).

However, with a new, throwaway sockpuppet account on Stack Overflow, I see only:

> Before confirming that you would like your profile deleted, we'd like to take a moment to explain the implications of deletion:
>
> - Deletion is irreversible, and you will have no way to regain any of your original content, should this deletion be carried out and you change your mind later on.
> - Your questions and answers will remain on the site, but will be disassociated and anonymized (the author will be listed as "userXXXXXXXX") and will not indicate your authorship even if you later return to the site.
>
> Confirming deletion will only delete your profile on Stack Overflow - it will not affect any of your other profiles on the Stack Exchange network. If you want to delete multiple profiles, you'll need to visit each site separately and request deletion of those individual profiles.
>
> ☑️ I have read the information stated above and understand the implications of having my profile deleted. I wish to proceed with the deletion of my profile.

So, evidently, the "We're sorry to hear you would like your profile to be deleted; lettuce taco about it" paragraph is only shown to certain users under certain circumstances (presumably, accounts in good standing who have some posts and/or reputation?).

When my throwaway sockpuppet account is *suspended*, the message on the "Delete Profile" page changes to:

> Before confirming that you would like your profile deleted, we'd like to take a moment to explain the implications of deletion:
>
> - Deletion is irreversible, and you will have no way to regain any of your original content, should this deletion be carried out and you change your mind later on.
> - Your questions and answers will remain on the site, but will be disassociated and anonymized (the author will be listed as "userXXXXXXXX") and will not indicate your authorship even if you later return to the site.
>
> While you are suspended from the site, we recommend that you take a break from the site and come back with a clear mind. We will not prevent you from deleting your profile if you still wish to do so, but do know that creating a new profile will automatically reinstate the remaining time of the previous suspension.
>
> Your profile appears to be currently blocked from posting either questions or answers. The intention of a posting block is to ask that you work on your existing content before trying to post further. Creating a new profile might help for a little bit, but if you ignore the advice below, you'll likely just end up blocked again. We cannot emphasize this enough: the best way to avoid being blocked is to learn from your mistakes and do your best to correct them.
>
> If you would like your ability to post reinstated, please follow the suggestions offered here:
>
> - [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/)
> - [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
> - [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
>
> The voting on your content is a measurement of how much the community finds your content worthwhile. If you can improve your existing questions enough to get them upvoted, your ability to post again will be reinstated automatically by the system.
>
> Note that learning to ask good questions is useful for reasons besides lifting the block - you'll find that folks are more willing to help, provide better answers, and are generally nicer when you're able to communicate with them effectively and demonstrate a willingness to be a part of the community.
>
> Confirming deletion will only delete your profile on Stack Overflow - it will not affect any of your other profiles on the Stack Exchange network. If you want to delete multiple profiles, you'll need to visit each site separately and request deletion of those individual profiles.
>
> ☑️ I have read the information stated above and understand the implications of having my profile deleted. I wish to proceed with the deletion of my profile.

As you can see, attempting to delete an account that has been suspended adds several additional paragraphs of cautionary tale. Presumably, some or all of this would be displayed when attempting to delete an account that has been question-banned but not explicitly suspended. (I believe that suspension is an implicit question+answer ban for the purposes of this message, since accounts that are suspended are blocked from posting. However, I assume that this text is only displayed on sites that have the question/answer ban(s) enabled.) Therefore, **I think (but cannot confirm with certainty) that this is the full template**:

> ## Delete Profile
>
> ---
>
> Before confirming that you would like your profile deleted, we'd like to take a moment to explain the implications of deletion:
>
> - Deletion is irreversible, and you will have no way to regain any of your original content, should this deletion be carried out and you change your mind later on.
> - Your questions and answers will remain on the site, but will be disassociated and anonymized (the author will be listed as "$UserDefaultDisplayName") and will not indicate your authorship even if you later return to the site.
>
> `<!-- If user account is currently suspended:`
>
> While you are suspended from the site, we recommend that you take a break from the site and come back with a clear mind. We will not prevent you from deleting your profile if you still wish to do so, but do know that creating a new profile will automatically reinstate the remaining time of the previous suspension.
>
> `-->`
>
> `<!-- If user account is currently question- or answer-banned:`
>
> Your profile appears to be currently blocked from posting either questions or answers. The intention of a posting block is to ask that you work on your existing content before trying to post further. Creating a new profile might help for a little bit, but if you ignore the advice below, you'll likely just end up blocked again. We cannot emphasize this enough: the best way to avoid being blocked is to learn from your mistakes and do your best to correct them.
>
> If you would like your ability to post reinstated, please follow the suggestions offered here:
>
> - [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/)
> - [How to Ask](https://$SiteUrl/help/how-to-ask)
> - [How to Answer](https://$SiteUrl/help/how-to-answer)
>
> The voting on your content is a measurement of how much the community finds your content worthwhile. If you can improve your existing questions enough to get them upvoted, your ability to post again will be reinstated automatically by the system.
>
> Note that learning to ask good questions is useful for reasons besides lifting the block - you'll find that folks are more willing to help, provide better answers, and are generally nicer when you're able to communicate with them effectively and demonstrate a willingness to be a part of the community.
>
> `-->`
>
> `<!-- If user account is *not* currently suspended, (*not* question- or answer-banned?,) *and* is in "good standing":`
>
> We're sorry to hear you would like your profile to be deleted. While we respect your decision to proceed with this process, we'd like to offer you the option of having any concerns or specific incidents heard out before doing so. If you'd like to talk to someone, please feel free to [contact us](https://$SiteUrl/contact) for further assistance.
>
> `-->`
>
> Confirming deletion will only delete your profile on $SiteName - it will not affect any of your other profiles on the Stack Exchange network. If you want to delete multiple profiles, you'll need to visit each site separately and request deletion of those individual profiles.
>
> ☑️ I have read the information stated above and understand the implications of having my profile deleted. I wish to proceed with the deletion of my profile.

Comment: Yes, a suspension [also results in an automatic question and answer ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363559/377214) for the duration of the suspension. Also, Meta Stack Overflow is the only network site where automatic quality bans are disabled - the text isn't applicable since attempting to access the profile deletion page on MSO or another per-site meta will redirect to the main site's version.

Comment: Regarding the "good standing" paragraph, I think it's shown to users who have enough activity that their voting record will have to be checked by an employee to determine if their votes should be preserved. I saw somewhere that some additional text is shown to those users, and I think those are the ones.

Comment: Many thanks for your research!